# ASp.net Entity Framework multiple identity user entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm currently refactoring multiple applications which access the same database for users. Each adds their own special properties to the user which results in a lot of null values... i do not like this. My idea was to use a own IdentityUser, dbContext and UserManager per Application. 
There is a base IdentityUser and the other ones derive from it. it looks like this:

The base user:

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
 {
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
   ...
 }
```

The dbContext and userManager for this user:

```
public class UserAuthenticationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
  //code here
}

public class UserManager : UserManager<User>
{
 //code here
}
```

For the second user i did the following:

```
[Table("User2")]
public class User2 : User
{
    public string SpecialProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string SpecialProperty2 {get;set;}
}

public class User2Manager : UserManager<User2>
{
  // code here
}

public class User2AuthenticationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User2>
{
   //code here
}
```

The User2 table only has the two Properties for example. The Primary Key in User2 is the same as in the User Table and also a FK to it.

In an asp.net mvc Project i use only for example the User2 related classes. If i now start this application i get instantly the error message "Invalid Column name SpecialProperty1 and SpecialProperty2".
Entity Frameworks seems to access the User Table which does not have this additional fields. It does not "merge" it with the User2 Table and return a User2 Entity. 
What can i do to achieve this or is there a different/better way on how to do it?

My main goal is to make this more clean and separate for this multiple applications while still all applications access the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to have is:

`XYZ.Business.Enities.DLL (Class Library)` - where you define your User classes:

```
class BaseUser
class User1 : BaseUser
class User2 : BaseUser
etc
```

`XYZ.Infrastructure.DataRepository.DLL (Class Library)` - your data repo, where you would have something like:

```
public IDbSet<BaseUser> Users
```

Based on that DLL you generate your database schema (Ef code-first). You will have a Users table with a `Discriminator` column (possible types: BaseUser, User1, User2, etc).

Your applications should reference the same common `Entities` assembly. In each application work with the specific user type.

e.g.

App1:

```
User1 user = new User1();
this.dataRepository.Users.Add(user);
```

App2:

```
User2 user = new User2();
this.dataRepository.Users.Add(user);
```

App3:
`var users = this.dataRepository.Users.Where(user is User3)`

The point is... your different applications should reference the same Entities and Repository DLLs.

Maybe on top of your `DataRepository` you can build a generic user repo, which does the enforcement. Something along the lines of

```
public class UserRepository<T> where T : BaseUser
{
  public UserRepository(IDataRepository dataRepository)
  {
  }

  // ... expose underlying dataRepository.Users here, while enforcing the T
}
```

then you can have in your apps:

```
var userRepo = new UserRepository<User1>(this.DataRepository);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I put it in an own Class library so it can be accessed from all aplications. In your example everything would still be in one single table right? just seperated with a column which holds the typename or something. Is there a way to do this with TablePerType? Like for example here: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt this is what i tried to do but i then get the error message in the mvc application...

Comment: in my example all the users will be in the same table and EF will determine what the record is in that table automatically, based on the Discriminator column. You will have column for each property of each class. If you don't want to have duplication, you should have inheritance and common base classes. However, you will always end up having some NULL columns (which are irrelevant for a record of some type) - this should not bother you.

Comment: Why are you thinking about the database? If you go EF-code first approach, it should not be something that is bothering you.

Comment: probably you are right. i bother too much about it :). i will try it with your approach and see if the error in the mvc application now goes away. thank you.